# Cannot receive mails from outbound.protection.outlook.com

Tags: centos, postfix

Im configuring a Kaspersky Secure mail Gateway to secure mail traffic coming to my exchange server.

Kaspersky secure mail Gateway is a centos Appliance running postfix.

I have no issue sending mails but I have some about receiving.

For example, all incoming mails from *.outbound.protection.outlook.com generate the Following errors on logs

```
postfix/smtpd[28748]: connect from mail-oln040092073107.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.73.107]
postfix/smtpd[28748]: setting up TLS connection from mail-oln040092073107.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.73.107]
postfix/smtpd[28748]: warning: network_biopair_interop: error reading 11 bytes from the network: Connection reset by peer
postfix/smtpd[28748]: SSL_accept error from mail-oln040092073107.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.73.107]: -1
postfix/smtpd[28748]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mail-oln040092073107.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.73.107]
postfix/smtpd[28748]: disconnect from mail-oln040092073107.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.73.107]
```

Kaspersky Secure mail Gateway is configured to negociate TLS session with the other side

I hope you can help me get rid of the problem.

Comment: Does any other sender succeed in establishing TLS and submitting mail?

Comment: Yes, there some mails who are received,

Comment: It seems we can receive mails from exchange users but not from office365 users or gmail users.